# convert string to dict python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string which I would like to turn into a dict.

my string:

```
minmax = "min: " + min(allvalueslist) + ", " + "max: " + max(allvalueslist)
```

output:

```
min: 29.47, max: 35.96
```

I imagined that the following code would work but it failed:

```
minmax = dict("min: " + min(allvalueslist) + ", " + "max: " + max(allvalueslist))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has bad length; 2 is required
```

Comment: Errr: `minmax = {'min': min(your_list), 'max': max(your_list)}` ?

Comment: try `minmax = dict(min=min(allvalueslist), max=max(allvalueslist))`

Comment: Any reason why you try to pass by a string? why not doing minmax = dict(min=min(allvalueslist), max=max(allvalueslist))?

Comment: Why on earth you need it __from__ a string?

Comment: @ Syed Habib M. Thanks, your code works too!

Comment: @PauloBu, Colin Bernet, I simply didnt know you could do that to be honest. Just ignorance on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
minmax = {
    "min":min(allvalueslist),
    "max":max(allvalueslist)
}
```

And in order to use it:

```
a = minmax["min"]
b = minmax["max"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
minmax = {"min": min(allvalueslist),  "max": max(allvalueslist)}
```